# Expo React Native google auth with firebase not working in published apk version on android

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, expo

I wanted to include google Auth in my app but it is not working in the published version on android even though it worked with expo
Here is the code:

```
logInGoogle = async () => {

try {
  const result = await Google.logInAsync({

    androidClientId:ID,
    iosClientId:ID,
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
    behavior:'web'
  });

  if (result.type === "success") {
    const { idToken, accessToken } = result;
    const credential = GoogleProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
    Firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(function(result){
        if(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){
          Firebase.database().ref('UserToQuestion/' + Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({

            notifier: {
              Email:Firebase.auth().currentUser.email

            }
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Alert.alert(error)
        console.log("firebase cred err:", error);
      });
  } else {
    return { cancelled: true };
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log("err:", err);
}

  }
```

Here is my app.json for android

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.aparson.SFS",
  "versionCode": 1

},
```

In the google console, I have a working service account but I have not configured the OAuth consent screen, but I am not sure if that is the problem because when I click the button for google login nothing happens at all. I have also changed the SHA-1 certificate to what the app signing showed which is what someone said to do in a different question but that did not work either.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use `expo-google-sign-in`

`expo-google-sign-in` provides native Google authentication for **standalone** Expo apps or bare React Native apps. It cannot be used in the Expo client as the native `GoogleSignIn` library expects your `REVERSE_CLIENT_ID` in the `info.plist` at build-time. To use Google authentication in the Expo client, check out `expo-google-app-auth` or `expo-app-auth`.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/#googleidentity